# regex return everything up to the first space after nth character

Tags: regex

I have a list of product names and I want to shorten them (Short Name). I need a regex that will return the first word if it is more than 5 characters and the first two words if it is 5 characters or less.

```
Product Name            Short Name
BABY WIPES MIS /ALOE    BABY WIPES
PKU GEL PAK             PKU GEL
CA ASCORBATE TAB 500MG  CA ASCORBATE
SOD SUL/SULF CRE 10-2%  SOD SUL/SULF
ASPIRIN TAB 81MG EC     ASPIRIN
IRON TAB 325MG          IRON TAB
PEDA                    PEDA
```

I initially used:

```
^([^ \t]+).*
```

but it only returns the first word so BABY WIPES MIS /ALOE would be BABY. I then tried:

```
.....([^ \t]+)
```

But this appears to not work for names less than 5 characters. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Brief

Your try is close, however, since you negated spaces and tabs, you were unable to move past the first word.

---

### Code

[See code in use here](https://regex101.com/r/zeaPbt/4)

```
^(\S{1,5}[ \t]*?\S+).*$
```

**Note:** The link uses the following shortened regex. `\h` may not work in your flavour of regex, which is why the code above is posted as well.

```
^(\S{1,5}\h*?\S+).*$
```

Super-simplified it becomes `^\S{1,5}\h*?\S+` (without capture groups and `.*$` as the OP initially used.)

---

### Results

#### Input

```
BABY WIPES MIS /ALOE
PKU GEL PAK
CA ASCORBATE TAB 500MG
SOD SUL/SULF CRE 10-2%
ASPIRIN TAB 81MG EC
IRON TAB
PEDA
```

#### Output

```
BABY WIPES
PKU GEL
CA ASCORBATE
SOD SUL/SULF
ASPIRIN
IRON TAB
PEDA
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of a line
- `(\S{1,5}[ \t]*?\S+)` Capture group doing the following

  - `\S{1,5}` Match any non-whitespace character between 1 and 5 times
  - `[ \t]*?` Match space or tab characters any number of times, but as few as possible (note in PCRE regex, this can be replaced with `\h*?` to make it shorter)
  - `\S+` Match any non-whitespace character between one and unlimited times
- `.*` Match any character (except newline character assuming `s` modifier is off - it should be for this problem)
- `$` Assert position at the end of a line

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like this:

```
^\S{1,5} \S+|^\S+
or
^\S{1,5} ?\S*
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/fJntsl/1)**

[image]

By the way, if you want to replace a full line with the shortened version, then you can use this regex instead:

```
(^\S{1,5} \S+|^\S+).*
or
(^\S{1,5} ?\S*).*
```

With the replacement string `$1` or `\1` depending on your regex engine.

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/fJntsl/2)**